# Getting the name property of the TextField (as a Select Box) Material-UI via the event object from the onFocus prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been using the `"@material-ui/core": "4.11.2"` package with `"react": "16.8.6"`. In the `TextField` component when the `select` prop is `true`, I can't get the `name` property of the `TextField` from the `event` object in `handleFocus` function.

```
<TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        name="mySelectBox"
        select
        label="Select"
        value={currency}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
      >
        {currencies.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
</TextField>
```

Here is `handleFocus` and `handleChange` functions.

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(
      "event.target ==>",
      event.target,
      "event.target.name ==>", // mySelectBox
      event.target.name
    );
  };

  const handleFocus = (event) => {
    console.log(
      "event.target ==>",
      event.target,
      "event.target.name ==>", // undefined
      event.target.name
    );
  };
```

I create a complete example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-glwzk?file=/demo.js).

Comment: you can try onFocus={handleFocus.bind(null, name)}

Answer (score 2):

The Texfield does not directly pass the onFocus to the input. From [MUI](https://v4.mui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api),

> The ref is forwarded to the root element.
>
> Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element
> (FormControl).

The `onFocus` is passed to the FormControl element, which is a div, not an input, and doesn't have a name. You can use the [NativeSelect](https://v4.mui.com/api/native-select/) or pass the onFocus property to the input props, which didn't play out very well when I tried in the sandbox you provided.

The quickest solution for this is to pass a ref to the input, and on focus, get the name from the reference. This is what your code will look like then.

```
export default function MultilineTextFields() {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState("EUR");
  const inputRef = React.useRef()

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
    console.log(
      "event.target ==>",
      event.target,
      "event.target.name ==>",
      event.target.name
    );
  };

  const handleFocus = (event) => {
    console.log(
      "event.target ==>",
      inputRef,
      "event.target.name ==>",
      inputRef.current.node.name
    );
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
      inputRef= {inputRef}
        id="standard-select-currency"
        name="mySelectBox"
        select
        label="Select"
        value={currency}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
      >
        {currencies.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is the sandbox I used https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zjlz3?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `SelectProps` to the `TextField` and use `<option>` tag instead of `<MenuItem>` component as I am saying below:

```
<TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        name="mySelectBox"
        select
        label="Select"
        value={currency}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
        SelectProps={{ native: true }} // ************
      >
        {currencies.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
</TextField>
```

I modified your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-glwzk?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 0):

I checked with some console logging and noticed that the `name` property is not an attribute of the `event.target`. The `event.target` you have logged displays

```html
<div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="standard-select-currency-label standard-select-currency" id="standard-select-currency">$</div>
```

which has attributes `class`, `tabindex`, `role`, `aria-haspopup`, `aria-labelledby`, and `id`

but the sibling of your target which is accessed by `event.target.nextSibling` is

```html
<input name="mySelectBox" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput" aria-describedby="standard-select-currency-helper-text" value="USD"></input>
```

or

```html
<input name="mySelectBox" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput" aria-describedby="standard-select-currency-helper-text" value="EUR"></input>
```

depending on which currency you select
has attributes `name`,`aria-hidden`,`tabindex`,`class`,`aria-describedby` and `value`

then you can access the `name` attribute inside the `handleFocus` as
`event.target.nextSibling.getAttribute('name')` or `event.target.nextSibling.name`

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-d1tzh?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Because the `value` of `name` does not exist, it is `undefined`.

Comment: `event.target.nextSibling.attributes.name` gives an object

Comment: I forgot to remove the `attributes`.

Comment: aha! `event.target.nextSibling.attributes.name.value` should also work?

Comment: Definitely yes.